# How to use Finder to find all files that do not match a certain criteria?

Tags: finder, search, file

How can I use Finder's search feature to find all files that **do not** match a certain criteria?

For instance, all files that **don't** end in ".txt" in the current folder.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just typing the operand **NOT** before the criteria will do the trick.

So, in this case, typing `NOT .txt` will show all the files but the ones with the *.txt* extension.

Comment: Outstanding!  Also to add to this, if your search requirement has more than one word, you need to enclose them in quotes, like `Name > Matches > NOT "two words"`

Answer (score 0):

Exclude search results by using the '-' symbol

like this: Name -GMT

Will display filenames that don't include '-GMT'

Comment: Does not work for me. The operator NOT as answered by @Thecafremo is the one that works.